# Problema na logica de um sistema de abas com relacionamento entre tabelas

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, relacionamento

Pessoal tenho duas tabelas que se relacionam entre si. São elas:

Categoria:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 128);
        $table->string('slug', 128)->unique();
        $table->mediumText('body')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();

    });
}
```

Post:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('title', 128)->nullable();
        $table->string('slug', 128)->unique();
        $table->longText('post_content')->nullable();
        $table->mediumText('short_content')->nullable();

        //RELACIONES
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')
        ->onDelete('cascade')
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Model Categoria.

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function posts() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
}
```

Model Post

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function categories() {

        return $this->belongsTo("App\Category");
    }

}
```

Função do Controller que lista os dados

```
public function catposts() {

    $posts = Post::with('categories')->get();
    $cats = Categories::with('posts')->get();

    // dd($posts);

    return view('lista_posts', compact('posts','cats'));

}
```

E a view

```
                            <div class="TabControl">

                                <div id="header">
                                    <ul class="abas">
                                        @foreach($categories as $category)
                                        <li><div class="aba"><a href="#"><span>{{ $category->name }}</span></a></div></li>
                                        @endforeach   
                                    </ul>
                                </div>

                                <div id="content">

                                    <div class="conteudo">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            @foreach($posts as $post)
                                            <div class="helper">
                                                <h5 class="card-title">{{ $post->title }}</h5>
                                                <p class="card-text">{{ $post->short_content }}</p>
                                            </div>
                                            @endforeach  
                                        </div>    
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            </div>
```

O erro não é na verdade um erro de codigo, mas sim um problema de logica mesmo.
Esse sistema funciona da seguinte maneira.
No exemplo aqui tenho 4 abas onde lista 4 categorias, quando clico sobre a primeira aba/categoria, o sistema mostra o conteúdo 
 relacionado aquela categoria e assim sucessivamente. Mas o problema ocorre na parte do sistema que mostra o conteúdo pertencente aquela aba/categoria, pois para que funcione corretamente esse sistema e abas, tenho que fazer o loop dentro da div conteúdo, dai quando clico na primeira aba/categoria, ele mostra o conteúdo relacionado aquela categoria, quando clico na segundo aba/categoria ele mostra o conteúdo relacionado aquela segunda categoria e assim sucessivamente, e fazendo o forearch $post dentro da div conteúdo, que seria o correto, para que o sistema funcione, ele mostra o conteúdo das outras abas/categorias tudo na primeira aba/categoria, onde o conteúdo das outras abas/categoria, deveria ser mostrado somente quando fosse clicado sobre a aba/categoria.

Então o que eu preciso seria uma logica que funcione bem com esse sistema de abas, ou um outro sistema de abas que funcione com essa logica, se alguém souber de algum sistema me ajuda por favor, porque ja procurei na internet toda um sistema de abas que funcione com essa logica dos relacionamentos e não encontrei. Ficarei muito grato.

Comment: Qual o erro?...

Comment: A primeiro momento, corrija sua estrutura no html. Seu endforeach deve conter um fechamento de div a mais.

Comment: Você esqueceu de adicionar ou errou mesmo? Acrescente um `public` na função ` function categories` na classe `Post `

Comment: Na tabela `categories` não vejo chave estrangeira

Comment: È porque é um relacionamento de um para muitos, então a referencia é feita na tabela post, onde a chave estrangeira é category_id referenciando a a coluna id da tabela categorias. Sobre a function só faltou na hora de copiar e colar mas no codigo esta tudo certo.

Comment: O erro não é na verdade não é um erro, mas sim um problema de logica mesmo., para que o sistema de abas funcione corretamente eu tenho que fazer o forearch das categorias dentro da <li>, no caso o loop das categorias ta funcionando blz, o forearch percorre e criar as abas com todas as categorias, o problema esta na div que mostra o conteudo, es